# How to style labels in a css file

Tags: html, css, label

Home
Read Here

I made four labels in my HTML code with different texts. But I don't know how to specifically pick one to style in my css file.

Comment: Can you share your HTML code? Without looking at it, you can give them classes or use a variation of `:nth-of-type() { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to help fully without seeing your code but I would say apply an id="name_of_element" to each text element.

Then in you .css file use #id-name-here to apply styling to each text element individually.

```
#element_id_here {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

You can change the parameters to suite your needs but these are just an example.

Comment: I'm no expert but I get the job done!
Your welcome... :)